# How to use React Router V6 to navigate to an specific section of a page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Im trying to set up my page so when you click "candidates" in the NavBar it goes to the Candidates section of the Home page (even if you're on another page). So far, I can only get it to scroll down if you click the Candidates button within the Home page using an  tag but when I try to use a  tag it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<nav className="w-full flex py-6 px-0 justify-between items-center navbar bg-red-gradient">
  <img src={logo} alt="hoobank" className="w-[124px] h-[32px]" />
  <ul className="list-none sm:flex hidden justify-end items-center flex-1 mr-5" >
    {navLinks.map((nav, index) => (
      <li 
        key={nav.id}
        className={`font-poppins font-normal cursor-pointer text-[16px] mr-8 text-white `}  
      >
        <Link to={nav.id === "home" ? "/" :`#${nav.id}`}>
        <a href={`#${nav.id}`} >
          {nav.title}
        </a>
        </Link>
      </li>
    ))}
    <Button2 />
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've built a component that solves this problem passively in the background without having to modify any react-router Links. Works with React-Router v6.

https://github.com/ncoughlin/scroll-to-hash-element

Answer (score -2):

first of all you didn't post any code. But still i think, i got your answer. Please try to check react router hashlink that will helps to move to particular section of a page.
If you still facing issue just lemme know, i will help you.
Thanks

Comment: Just FYI [`react-router-hash-link`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) hasn't been updated to be compatible with `react-router@6`, so it's not a viable option here really.

Comment: I know @drew, but as i said, he didn't mention any code. And i think he's on lower version of react router, that's why i just give him a way to solve issue so that he can do rest things.

Comment: It's right in the title what version they are using/interested in: "How to use React Router V6 to navigate to an specific section of a page?"

Comment: Sorry, @drew i just read issue.. Thanks for information.. next time will be sure to check full information..

Comment: I just posted my code; I didn't post it at the beginning as I was looking forward to implementing something and starting over. If router hash link won't work, what else can I use? I can't seem to find it on the documentation.